# VS2010: "Unable to start debugging" - What's causing this?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, ide, client-server

I've been developing desktop applications with VB 2010 for years, and suddenly with this one project I am frequently getting this message when trying to run a debug session:

[image]

It doesn't do it all the time, but it is starting to do it with aggravating frequency. All I can do is close VS and re-open it again. It's getting tiresome.

There are a number of posts about this, but most of them are for web applications. The few that are for desktop apps have not provided a solution. There was one suggestion to delete the output folder and let VB recreate it new, but I have a number of dependencies in folders inside that folder.

Other considerations:

- This is a server program; it communicates with mobile clients over TCP.
- It connects to an Access database on a remote server -- the server where the production version runs.
- Updated the machine's OS from Windows 7 to Windows 10 a couple of months ago.
- Silverlight is not used.

One thing that I did hoping to fix it was, I added a "Terminate All" button to the menu bar. That helped with another problem I was having, but not with this.

Hoping someone has the answer!

Thanks!

Comment: check if you have internet connection when you get this error and try starting VS as admin?

Comment: @krish KM I have no reason to think that the internet connection is lost. I'll try your suggestion about starting as admin.

Comment: @krish KM Well, I'm sorry to say that running as admin didn't fix the problem. But thanks for the suggestion. I'm open to anything else you may think of.

Comment: Did something change in tools>options>debugging? Also check windows' event viewer for possible clues.